# Calculating Variance $V\big\{-\frac{2}{\sum_1^n x_i}\big\}, \; X_i \sim \Gamma(2,1/\theta)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, descriptive-statistics

I have some trouble calculating the following variance :

$$V\bigg\{-\frac{2}{\sum_1^n x_i}\bigg\}$$

where $X_i$ follow the Gamma Distribution $\sim \Gamma(2,1/\theta)$.

**Attempt :**

$X_i$ are independent and then :

$$V[X]=\frac{2}{\theta^2}$$

$$V\bigg\{-\frac{2}{\sum_1^n x_i}\bigg\} = \frac{2^2}{\sum_1^n V(x_i)}= \frac{4}{2n\theta^{-2}}=\frac{2\theta^2}{n}$$

But the correct result should be :

$$V = \frac{\theta^2}{2n}$$

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Why is there a negative sign? Also isn't the $\beta$ in the distrbution $\frac 1\theta$?

Comment: $V(1/X)\ne \frac{1}{V(X)}$.

Comment: If I am correct about the parametrisation you are using and assuming $X_i$'s to be iid, $T=\sum X_i$ should be a Gamma$\left(2n,\frac{1}{\theta}\right)$ variate. Then you are looking for the value $4\times V(1/T)$.

Comment: Some confusion here. To help clarify, can you please write the density function of $X_i?$